# Adding options to a <select> using jQuery only once

Tags: jquery

actually now i can add to my select some options, the question right now, 
how can i add the option just only once
here is my code right now:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select.tags-predefinis").on("change",function(e){
            var optionText = $(this).children("option:selected").text();

            if ($('#tags').find("option[value='" + optionText + "']").length) {
                $('#tags').val(optionText).trigger('change');
            } else {
                // Create a DOM Option and pre-select by default
                var newOption = new Option(optionText, optionText, true, true);
                // Append it to the select

                $('#tags').append(newOption).trigger('change');
            }




        });
    });





</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "just only once" part?  Is it adding a single option multiple times?

Comment: when i select the same option, 
the whole list will be removed

Comment: Can you update your fidde with a [mcve] showing the issue?  I don't see anything in the provided snippet that would destroy the list.

Comment: but it destroy my list.